# How to get only images from gallery

Tags: java, android, image

I want to get image from gallery and set as background in some layout.
What I do:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.SELECT_IMAGE);
```

This intent shows me a gallery and allows pick not only pictures, but video too. But I need **only images** for set to background. Give me please correct sample.

this way doesn't help:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: "this way doesn't help" -- since that is basically the right answer (I'd dump the `createChooser()` part), please explain what "doesn't help" means.

Comment: I don't want to see video files - I need only pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `ACTION_PICK`, for a MIME type of `image/*`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, Constants.SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: @Bender: Then there is a bug in the activity that the user is selecting based upon the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request.